# Can we make our StackOverflow site available to our personal devices?

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I tried using my smartphone to browse through our Stackoverflow threads. After doing MFA, it is requiring to have my personal device managed.

This is enforced by Conditional Access Policies in Azure AD.

Can we relax the policy for Stackoverflow so we can have the option of viewing and collaborating from any endpoints and devices?

Comment: Have you got any progress sir? Did you mean that because of enabling MFA, you have to do more authentication on your phone when you visit stackoverflow?\

Comment: Hi @Tiny-wa - Conditional Access Policies are separate from MFA. MFA authenticates the user whereas CAPs determine (based on various signals like device management, IP address, session, application type, OS, etc) if you're authorized for the app you just authenticated with. I'll make some rounds with IT FP and Cyber but I believe Josh Phillips will be a good start.